# Parse numbers with delimiter - BASH

Tags: bash, shell-script

I would like to parse ports, for instance `45:68`. I defined testing var.

```
echo "ports"
read in
```

I splited ports to array:

```
IFS=":" read -ra port <<< "$in"
```

Ports must be less than 65535, contain only numbers and must be filled out. So I set while loop based on mentioned conditions.

```
    while [ -z "${port[@]}" ] || [[ "${port[0]}" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]] || [[ "${port[1]}" =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]] ||[ "${port[@]}" -gt 65535 ]
         do
            port=$(whiptail --title "No!" --inputbox --nocancel "Error MSG." 12 50 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
         done
```

After I had executed my script I got stucked in loop.

Is there some better way to parse ports successfully?

Comment: A `while` loop will continue forever _while_ a condition exists. You might want to consider a `for` loop that will iterate over each array element in turn.

Answer (score 0):

Use `for` loop as suggested by @roamia and validate each element with `if`

```
for current_port in "${port[@]}"; do
  if ! [[ -n $current_port && $current_port =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ && $current_port -le 65535 ]]; then
    port=$(whiptail --title "No!" --inputbox --nocancel "Error MSG." 12 50 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
  fi
done
```

P.S why are you seeking dash `-` in port number?

Comment: Note that it would accept a `port_number` of `0150000` (octal for 53248 which is less than 65536) for instance. And you'd get an error message for `0990`. You may want to switch to `zsh`, or use `[ "$current_port" -le 65535 ]` (the standard `[` command instead of the `[[...]]` ksh construct) or add a check for those octal numbers.